# Multiple array check react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects which I'm rendering by section - see title of each object "Price", "Sectors and Charges" etc.

This populates a mini modal where users can select options to update rendered columns basically a filter.

The selection of the items are working however if I make a selection of the first item "0" all sections with the first option are selected.

How can I store the selection from each object into the selectedOptions array?

Please note I'm using react js and styled components, I've not added the styled component code.

Data:

```
const columnsData = [
    {
        title: 'Price',
        options: [
            {
                label: 'Daily Change'
            },
            {
                label: 'Price'
            },
            {
                label: 'Price Date'
            },
            {
                label: 'Volatility Rating'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Sectors and Charges',
        options: [
            {
                label: 'Sector'
            },
            {
                label: 'Asset Class'
            },
            {
                label: 'AMC'
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Cumulative Performance',
        options: [
            {
                label: '1 month'
            },
            {
                label: '6 months'
            },
            {
                label: '1 year'
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Code:

```
const EditColumns = ({active, onClick}) => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([0, 1, 2]);

    const update = () => {
        onClick();
    }

    const updateSelection = (z) => {
        setSelectedOptions(selectedOptions.includes(z) ? selectedOptions.filter(j => j !== z) : [...selectedOptions, z]);
    }

    return (
        <Wrap onClick={() => update()}>
            <CTA>
                <SVG src="/assets/svgs/btns/edit.svg" />
                <span>Columns</span>
            </CTA>
            {active &&
                <Dropdown>
                    <Head>
                        <span className="title">Edit Columns</span>
                        <span>Select the columns you would like to see</span>
                    </Head>
                    <Body>
                        {columnsData.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <Section key={i}>
                                    <SectionHead>
                                        <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
                                        <span>Select all</span>
                                    </SectionHead>
                                    <SectionList>
                                        {item.options.map((child, z) => {
                                            const selected = selectedOptions.includes(z);                                       
                                            return (
                                                <li key={z} className={classNames({selected})} onClick={() => updateSelection(z)}>
                                                    <span>{child.label}</span>
                                                </li>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </SectionList>
                                </Section>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Body>
                </Dropdown>
            }   
        </Wrap>
    )
}

export default EditColumns;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your section lists are all sharing the same state variable, so any changes will be applied to all of them. You could fix this either by constructing a more complex state object which more closely resembles the structure of `columnsData`, or making each `SectionList` its own component with its own state. What you decide to do will depend on the degree to which the `EditButtons` component actually needs access to the whole state.

The second approach might look something like this:

```
const EditColumns = ({active, onClick}) => {
    const update = () => {
        onClick();
    }

    return (
        <Wrap onClick={() => update()}>
            <CTA>
                <SVG src="/assets/svgs/btns/edit.svg" />
                <span>Columns</span>
            </CTA>
            {active &&
                <Dropdown>
                    <Head>
                        <span className="title">Edit Columns</span>
                        <span>Select the columns you would like to see</span>
                    </Head>
                    <Body>
                        {columnsData.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <Section key={i}>
                                    <SectionHead>
                                        <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
                                        <span>Select all</span>
                                    </SectionHead>
                                    <SectionList options={item.options}/>
                                </Section>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Body>
                </Dropdown>
            }   
        </Wrap>
    )
}
```

```
const SectionList = ({options}) => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([0, 1, 2]);

    const updateSelection = (z) => {
        setSelectedOptions(selectedOptions.includes(z) ? selectedOptions.filter(j => j !== z) : [...selectedOptions, z]);
    }

    return (
        <SectionListContainer>
            {options.map((child, z) => {
                const selected = selectedOptions.includes(z);                                       
                return (
                    <li key={z} className={classNames({selected})} onClick={() => updateSelection(z)}>
                        <span>{child.label}</span>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </SectionListContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you will try this approach.